# testcontainers: how to fix bind source path does not exist

Tags: docker, go, testing

I'm trying to run a container using testcontainers. Here is my code:

```
func createContainer(ctx context.Context) (testcontainers.Container, *gorm.DB, string, error) {
    var env = map[string]string{
        "POSTGRES_PASSWORD": DbPass,
        "POSTGRES_USER":     DbUser,
        "POSTGRES_DB":       DbName,
    }
    var port = "5432/tcp"

    path := `C:/Desktop/Folder/golang/TgBotReminder/internal/db/postgresql/migration/notes.sql`

    req := testcontainers.GenericContainerRequest{
        ContainerRequest: testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
            Image:        "postgres:latest",
            ExposedPorts: []string{port},
            Env:          env,
            WaitingFor:   wait.ForLog("database system is ready to accept connections"),
            SkipReaper:   true,
            Mounts: testcontainers.Mounts(
                testcontainers.BindMount(path, "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"),
            ),
        },
        Started: true,
    }
...
```

The directory I've mentioned in the path variable exists. But I got the error: `Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /pipe/docker_engine: creating reaper failed: failed to create container`.
I got this error even if I comment lines with Mounts.
How to fix it? And also is it correct to type filename in the path variable ("notes.sql")? Or should I only type the directory here?

Thank you in advance

**Update 1**

I also tried this code right now:

```
container, err := tspostgres.RunContainer(ctx,
        testcontainers.WithImage("postgres:latest"),
        tspostgres.WithInitScripts(filepath.Join(".", "test_migration", "notes.sql")),
        tspostgres.WithDatabase("test-db"),
        tspostgres.WithUsername("postgres"),
        tspostgres.WithPassword("postgres"),
        testcontainers.WithWaitStrategy(
            wait.ForLog("database system is ready to accept connections").
                WithOccurrence(2).WithStartupTimeout(5*time.Second)),
    )

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

got the same error

**Update 2**

Here is another piece of code I've tried:

```
path := `/${PWD}/desktop/folder/golang/tgbotreminder/internal/db/postgresql/migration/notes.sql`
target := "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/"
...
Mounts: testcontainers.ContainerMounts{
                testcontainers.ContainerMount{
                    Source: testcontainers.GenericBindMountSource{
                        HostPath: path,
                    },
                    Target: testcontainers.ContainerMountTarget(target),
                },
            },
```

No luck again :(

**Update 3**

Here is my another attempt:

```
Mounts: testcontainers.Mounts(testcontainers.ContainerMount{
                Source: testcontainers.GenericBindMountSource{
                        HostPath: path,
                },
                Target: testcontainers.ContainerMountTarget(target),
        }),
```

It also doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered the same issue on my machine. The full error message is:

```
2023/07/11 12:15:35 github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go - Connected to docker:
  Server Version: 20.10.14
  API Version: 1.41
  Operating System: Docker Desktop
  Total Memory: 7912 MB
2023/07/11 12:15:35  Creating container for image docker.io/testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1
panic: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /pipe/docker_engine: creating reaper failed: failed to create container
```

As pointed out by @pratheesh-pc, It means that it failed to create the container from the image `docker.io/testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1`. It has nothing to do with the mounts configuration of your own container that you want to create. I think the link provided in @pratheesh-pc's answer is for Windows Container on Windows (WCOW), but I encountered the issue when running Linux Container on Windows (LCOW).

A workaround is to disable the reaper. In fact, you have set `SkipReaper: true` in your code and you meant to disable the reaper. The problem is, from [github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go@v0.20.0](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go/releases/tag/v0.20.0), `SkipReaper` is totally ignored, and you have to disable it with one of [the following approaches](https://golang.testcontainers.org/features/garbage_collector/#ryuk):

1. adding `ryuk.disabled=true` to the `.testcontainers.properties` file. On Windows, the full path of the file is `C:/Users/%my_username%/.testcontainers.properties`.
2. setting the `TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true` environment variable. This manner takes precedence over the properties file.

Comment: thanks! i've set the `TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true` but it didn't help. I'm looking for `.testcontainers.properties` but can't find it

Comment: i've created file `.testcontainers.properties` on my own and wrote there `ryuk.disabled=true` and it fixed the problem

Comment: On Windows, you can set the environment variable with `setx TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED true`. Or setting it with the UI. If the `.testcontainers.properties` file does not exist, you can create one.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the issue is with the image `Ryuk` and some hard-coded values which is not compatible with `windows`.

> testcontainers-go currently doesn't support "Windows containers": it has some hard-coded defaults that don't consider the possibility of Windows containers.

See https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go/issues/948

Comment: thank you for your answer! now it's clear what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the issue lies with the Mounts try:

```
Mounts: []testcontainers.Mount{
            {
                Source: path,
                Target: "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/notes.sql",
                Type:   testcontainers.BindMountType,
            },
        },
```

when specifying the source path for a bind mount, you should provide the complete path to the file, including the file name itself. So, it is correct to include the filename ("notes.sql") in the path variable.

Comment: so what should I do to fix this error?

Comment: the code is right above ^

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work: `unknown field DockerEndpoint in struct literal of type testcontainers.ContainerRequest`

Comment: ah you are right, try the edit.

Comment: well i've already tried this code for some time ago ,but let me try again

Comment: I've tried it. your code is not completely correct. I've tried the correct one (updated my question so you can see it) and got the same err again :(

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

created a file `.testcontainers.properties` in the `C:/Users/%my_username%/` and wrote there: `ryuk.disabled=true`